# Cannot subscript a value of type '[Post]'

Tags: arrays, swift

I got that error a while ago and I'm not sure, what's wrong. The `Post` is just normal custom class with two attributes of type `String` and initializer. My class have an attribute of type `[Post]`, which is basically an array of type `Post` (I think it's same as `Array<Post>`, but I'm not sure).
I'm trying to get a `Post` at specific index via `Int`, but it doesn't work.

This is the file where exception occurs:

```
import UIKit

class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var news = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        news = [Post(title: "Aplikace ITNetwork spuštěna.", author: User(name: "jan.ruzicka01", portfolio: "http://www.itnetwork.cz/portfolio/15392"))]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return news.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("carCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = news[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that is the exact error message? I would assume the actual problem is trying to assign the `Post` to the `text` attribute.

Comment: You're right, silly me, but the error message is same as I wrote in title.

Comment: You did not understand me correctly - I do not think your error message is the actual error, try writing `let post = news[indexPath.row]` and in the next line write `cell.textLabel!.text = post`. What is error then?

Comment: I understood you correctly, but my english is too bad, so you did not understand that from my higher comment. I understand that the error is not with the index, but with the type of returned value. But the error message remains same. If I write the code as you said there, it obviously says: 'Cannot assign value of type 'Post' to value of type 'String'' I don't say you think the error message is actual error, I'm just saying that some bug in compiler happened so it shows wrong error message. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as luk2302 mentioned, the actual error was the assignment of value of type 'Post' to value of type 'String', but compiler showed wrong error, so I was confused.